# Office JS - refresh add-in version

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm writing new features for a Word add-in that is already published in the Store. When I publish a new add-in version, it is visible only to users who remove the previous version and reinstall the add-in. (Simply restarting Word didn't do the trick.)

Is there a way to have the add-in update automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the add-in itself (the website), changes happen immediately upon publishing to your server just as they would for any other web application. For the manifest, once you publish an update to the Store it will automatically update the manifest on the client when it sees a bump in the version number.

Comment: I thought this should be the case, but it doesn't seem to happen in practice. We see the new version only when we manually remove the add-in from Word and then reinstall it. Maybe it's not due to MS mechanics. We're hosting it on AWS and after each deployment, we invalidate the files (otherwise nothing happens). Maybe we need to do something more.

Comment: The manifest only holds the landing page URI, everything else is handled externally. Clearly, if you have cache control on the files, you will need to force invalidation. For manifests, you need to be sure and bump the version number in order to force the client to update. Note that side-loaded add-ins may need to be uninstalled/re-installed.

Comment: This is a side loaded add-in (if that means that, when clicked on it, it literally loads on the right side of Word, next to the paper). Does that mean it may need to be uninstalled/re-installed?

Comment: Side-loaded means you installed it manually rather than via the O365 Admin Center or Office Store. See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks. Also, I've found the real issue. My colleague made introduced a little bug to the deployment process and set a maximum caching time to index.html (instead of no-cache..). Thanks and sorry for the trouble!